# Using spl_autoloading within WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, php

I'm struggling with `spl_autoloading` inside a namespaced WordPress Plugin.

I already revised these questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806301/best-way-to-autoload-classes-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847329/wordpress-plugin-with-classes-namespaces-and-psr-0-autoloading

My folder structure looks like that:

Namespacing everything below `SamplePlugin`

inside `wp-content/plugins/sample-plugin`

```
    src
     '-- SamplePlugin
     '   '-- ShortCode.php
     '-- autoload.php
    sample-plugin.php
```

My current autoload function (as I'm used to doing it...)

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

$dir = 'src/';
$file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

require_once $dir . $file;
```

Using that, the prefixing namespace is correctly added, so if I instantiate in `sample-plugin.php`:

```
namespace SamplePlugin;
require_once 'src/autoload.php';

$shortcode = new ShortCode();
```

I get the following output (VVV):

> Warning: require_once(src/SamplePlugin/ShortCode.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/sample-plugin/src/autoload.php on line 8
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'src/SamplePlugin/ShortCode.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/sample-plugin/src/autoload.php on line 8

Any hints?

All Classes (e.g. ShortCode are callable through SamplePlugin\Shortcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're using a **relative path** in `autoload.php` inside the `src/` subfolder,

Try for example to modify your `src/autoload.php` to use **absolute paths** instead:

```
\spl_autoload_register( function( $class )
{
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

    $file = str_replace( '\\', '/', $class ) . '.php';

    $path = $dir . $file;

    if( file_exists( $path ) )
        require_once $path;

} );
```

where we add a `file_exists` to be *plugin class specific*.

### Update

Here's the main `/sample-plugin/sample-plugin.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Sample Plugin
 */

namespace SamplePlugin;

require_once __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';
// require_once 'src/autoload.php';

$shortcode = new ShortCode();
```

Here's the `/simple-plugin/src/SamplePlugin/Shortcode.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Shortcode
 */

namespace SamplePlugin;

class Shortcode
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print 'DEBUG: Greetings from the Shortcode instance!';
    }
}
```

You could also check out how [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) generates the `vendor/autoload.php` file, that's included with:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Hey, I did try working with absolute paths already. All it does is changing the paths in the error output.

Comment: I just tested your plugin structure and this modification works on my install. @PascaleBeier